# Regex R lookbehind

Tags: r, regex, stringr

How can I find the `n` words before the `colon` in this string in `R`? I'm using `stringr` but would regular expressions would be prefered.

```
Input on income economic activities: Small business, self-emp…
```

Thanks,
E.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do:

```
str_extract(str, "(\\w+ ?){3}:")

[1] "income economic activities:"
```

Replace the `3` for your `n`

Answer (score 1):

Base R solution:

```
n <- 4
pattern <- paste0("(\\w+ ?){", n, "}(?=:)")
regmatches(s, regexpr(pattern, s, perl = T))

[1] "on income economic activities"
```